# ¿Cómo manipular gráficos o figuras embebidas en Frames?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, interfaz-gráfica, matplotlib

***¡Hola Comunidad!***

Se tiene una *GUI* implementada mediante la librería de Tkinter en la que el usuario podrá conocer el área de un polígono de cuatro (4) lados y, posteriormente, se mostrará la figura del mismo. Para ello, deberá introducir dos (2) valores correspondientes a la base y altura de la figura.

En el código de la app fueron creados dos (2) widgets de tipo Frame; uno para contener los widgets de los valores de entrada (base y altura), mientras que el otro será para contener la información relacionada con el área de la figura.

Además, luego que se realiza el cálculo del área, se mostrará un gráfico contenido dentro de un tercer Frame, el  cual estará compuesto por objetos del backend de `matplotlib` para la libería `tkinter`, conocidos como `Figure` y `FigureCanvasTkAgg`.

**El código está definido como:**

```
import tkinter as tk
import numpy as np

import matplotlib
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

class App:

    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()

        # Contenedor principal
        contenedor_fm = tk.Frame(self.root)
        contenedor_fm.pack(fill='both', expand=1)

        # Frame para valores de entrada
        fm1 = tk.Frame(contenedor_fm)
        fm1.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=10)

        # Frame para resultados
        fm2 = tk.Frame(contenedor_fm)
        fm2.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=5, pady=10)

        # Frame para gráficos
        fm3 = tk.Frame(contenedor_fm)
        fm3.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=55, pady=10)

        # Widgets para fm1
        tk.Label(fm1, text='Ingrese base y altura'
            ).grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=4)
        tk.Label(fm1, text='Base:'
            ).grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='e')
        tk.Label(fm1, text='Altura:'
            ).grid(row=1, column=2, sticky='e')

        # Función para cuando se presione el botón
        def calcular():
            area.set(base.get() * altura.get())

            # Widgets para fm3
            b = np.array([0, base.get(), base.get(), 0, 0])
            a = np.array([0, 0, altura.get(), altura.get(), 0])

            figura = Figure(figsize=(2, 2), dpi=100)
            ax1 = figura.add_subplot(111)
            ax1.plot(b, a)

            canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(figura, master=fm3)
            canvas.draw()
            canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(padx=25)

        # Valores dados por el usuario
        base = tk.IntVar(value=0) 
        altura = tk.IntVar(value=0)
        area = tk.IntVar(value=0)

        base_entry = tk.Entry(fm1, textvariable=base, 
            width=5)
        base_entry.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='w')

        altura_entry = tk.Entry(fm1, textvariable=altura, 
            width=5)
        altura_entry.grid(row=1, column=3)

        # Botón para realizar el cálculo
        calcular_btn = tk.Button(fm1, text='Calcular',
            command=calcular)
        calcular_btn.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=4)

        # Widgets para fm2
        tk.Label(fm2, text='El área de polígono es:'
            ).grid(row=0, column=0)
        tk.Label(fm2, textvariable=area).grid(row=0, column=1)

    def mainloop(self):
        self.root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ejemplo = App()
    ejemplo.mainloop()
```

**Interrogantes:**

1. Al momento que se crea la figura se puede apreciar que esta tiene la misma escala en ambos ejes. Es decir, si el usuario introduce las dimensiones base=20 y altura=30, la visualización tendrá el aspecto de un cuadrado.
2. ¿Cómo mostrar solo la figura sin valores en los ejes? ("X" e "Y").
3. Si el usuario vuelve a introducir nuevos valores de `base` y `altura` y procede a calcular su `area`, la figura anterior se sigue mostrando en la app y se carga la nueva debajo de la anterior. ¿Cómo entonces se puede "resetear" el gráfico anterior y construir el nuevo en la misma posición?

***¡Gracias por sus comentarios y/o sugerencias!***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Al momento que se crea la figura se puede apreciar que esta tiene la
>   misma escala en ambos ejes.**

Por defecto la relación de aspecto de los ejes es automática, puedes conseguir que mantengan la proporción mediante:

```
   matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_aspect('equal')
```

> **¿Cómo mostrar solo la figura sin valores en los ejes? ("X" e "Y").**

```
   matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_axis_off()
```

ésto no solo ocultará los números (etiquetas), también las marcas del eje y la propia linea del mismo. Creo que se ajusta más a lo que buscas, aunque se pueden solo eliminar las etiquetas si lo deseas.

> **¿Cómo entonces se puede "resetear" el gráfico anterior y construir el nuevo en la misma posición?**

Existen varias formas, creo que en tu caso podrías hacer:

- Definir la figura, el eje y la instancia de `FigureCanvasTkAgg` en el incializador, con al menos éstos dos últimos como atributos de instancia para poder referenciarlos luego. La idea es reutilizar el eje creado.
- En el inicializador no llames al método `grid` del widget embebido  en el `FigureCanvasTkAgg` a no ser que quieras mostrar una figura en blanco desde el inicio.
- En al función `calcular`:

  - Posicionamos el canvas.
  - Llamamos a  `matplotlib.axes.Axes.clear()` para limpiar los ejes, eliminando la anterior figura si la hay.
  - Aplicamos los mencionados métodos de arriba para no mostrar los ejes y para la relación de aspecto.
  - Actualizamos el `FigureCanvasTkAgg` llamando a su método `show`.

---

```
import tkinter as tk
import numpy as np

import matplotlib
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure


class App:

    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()

        # Contenedor principal
        contenedor_fm = tk.Frame(self.root)
        contenedor_fm.pack(fill="y",  expand=True)

        # Frame para valores de entrada
        fm1 = tk.Frame(contenedor_fm)
        fm1.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=10)

        # Frame para resultados
        fm2 = tk.Frame(contenedor_fm)
        fm2.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=5, pady=10)

        # Frame para gráficos
        fm3 = tk.Frame(contenedor_fm)
        fm3.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=55, pady=10)

        figura = Figure(figsize=(2, 2), dpi=100)
        self.axes = figura.add_subplot(111)
        self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(figura, master=fm3)



        # Widgets para fm1
        tk.Label(fm1, text='Ingrese base y altura'
            ).grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=4)
        tk.Label(fm1, text='Base:'
            ).grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='e')
        tk.Label(fm1, text='Altura:'
            ).grid(row=1, column=2, sticky='e')

        # Función para cuando se presione el botón
        def calcular():
            area.set(base.get() * altura.get())

            # Widgets para fm3
            b = np.array([0, base.get(), base.get(), 0, 0])
            a = np.array([0, 0, altura.get(), altura.get(), 0])

            self.canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(padx=25)
            self.axes.clear()
            self.axes.plot(b, a)
            self.axes.set_aspect('equal')
            self.axes.set_axis_off()
            self.canvas.draw()

        # Valores dados por el usuario
        base = tk.IntVar(value=0)
        altura = tk.IntVar(value=0)
        area = tk.IntVar(value=0)

        base_entry = tk.Entry(fm1, textvariable=base, 
            width=5)
        base_entry.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='w')

        altura_entry = tk.Entry(fm1, textvariable=altura, 
            width=5)
        altura_entry.grid(row=1, column=3)

        # Botón para realizar el cálculo
        calcular_btn = tk.Button(fm1, text='Calcular',
            command=calcular)
        calcular_btn.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=4)

        # Widgets para fm2
        tk.Label(fm2, text='El área de polígono es:'
            ).grid(row=0, column=0)
        tk.Label(fm2, textvariable=area).grid(row=0, column=1)

    def mainloop(self):
        self.root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ejemplo = App()
    ejemplo.mainloop()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]